# Xamarin IOS app crash log

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have the following app crash log for a Tamarin IOS app that crashes only in AdHoc mode on a physical device.  Debug mode on the same device runs just fine.  I cannot seem to get the log symbolicated.  Here is the partial log with the crashing thread

```html
Date/Time:           2016-11-09 14:16:12.3887 -0600
Launch Time:         2016-11-09 14:16:11.9703 -0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_a07  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018721a014 0x1871fb000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001872e1460 0x1872dc000 + 21600
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x000000018718e3f4 0x18712b000 + 406516
3   LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001000dfdec 0x1000ac000 + 212460
4   libsystem_platform.dylib       0x00000001872db348 0x1872d5000 + 25416
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001872e1460 0x1872dc000 + 21600
6   libsystem_c.dylib              0x000000018718e3f4 0x18712b000 + 406516
7   LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001001b8e68 0x1000ac000 + 1101416
8   LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001000e0498 0x1000ac000 + 214168
9   LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001000dfaa8 0x1000ac000 + 211624
10  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001000ded04 0x1000ac000 + 208132
11  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001000d7e5c 0x1000ac000 + 179804
12  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100450318 0x1000ac000 + 3818264
13  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x000000010032cf70 0x1000ac000 + 2625392
14  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x000000010032cac0 0x1000ac000 + 2624192
15  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100354234 0x1000ac000 + 2785844
16  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c899f8 0x1000ac000 + 12442104
17  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c7c064 0x1000ac000 + 12386404
18  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c7bd10 0x1000ac000 + 12385552
19  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100a60614 0x1000ac000 + 10176020
20  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c7d3b4 0x1000ac000 + 12391348
21  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c7cfe8 0x1000ac000 + 12390376
22  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c81f74 0x1000ac000 + 12410740
23  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c81280 0x1000ac000 + 12407424
24  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c80364 0x1000ac000 + 12403556
25  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c7a2ac 0x1000ac000 + 12378796
26  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c7a210 0x1000ac000 + 12378640
27  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c7a404 0x1000ac000 + 12379140
28  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c78acc 0x1000ac000 + 12372684
29  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c7870c 0x1000ac000 + 12371724
30  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c78680 0x1000ac000 + 12371584
31  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c1d1cc 0x1000ac000 + 11997644
32  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100c1d10c 0x1000ac000 + 11997452
33  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001001c29e4 0x1000ac000 + 1141220
34  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x000000010041b504 0x1000ac000 + 3601668
35  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001000ec3c4 0x1000ac000 + 263108
36  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001001435c0 0x1000ac000 + 619968
37  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100f2e270 0x1000ac000 + 15213168
38  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100f2e960 0x1000ac000 + 15214944
39  UIKit                          0x000000018e10742c 0x18e085000 + 533548
40  UIKit                          0x000000018e317b70 0x18e085000 + 2698096
41  UIKit                          0x000000018e31d8e0 0x18e085000 + 2722016
42  UIKit                          0x000000018e332080 0x18e085000 + 2805888
43  UIKit                          0x000000018e31a8c4 0x18e085000 + 2709700
44  FrontBoardServices             0x0000000189ded8bc 0x189db3000 + 239804
45  FrontBoardServices             0x0000000189ded728 0x189db3000 + 239400
46  FrontBoardServices             0x0000000189dedad0 0x189db3000 + 240336
47  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001881fa278 0x18811d000 + 905848
48  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001881f9bc0 0x18811d000 + 904128
49  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001881f77c0 0x18811d000 + 894912
50  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188126048 0x18811d000 + 36936
51  UIKit                          0x000000018e1005dc 0x18e085000 + 505308
52  UIKit                          0x000000018e0fb360 0x18e085000 + 484192
53  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100520c64 0x1000ac000 + 4672612
54  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x000000010049469c 0x1000ac000 + 4097692
55  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x000000010049465c 0x1000ac000 + 4097628
56  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001001c2984 0x1000ac000 + 1141124
57  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x000000010041b504 0x1000ac000 + 3601668
58  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001000ec3c4 0x1000ac000 + 263108
59  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001001435c0 0x1000ac000 + 619968
60  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100147a10 0x1000ac000 + 637456
61  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x00000001001c1f54 0x1000ac000 + 1138516
62  LaryngopediaMobileiOS          0x0000000100f4878c 0x1000ac000 + 15320972
63  libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001871085b8 0x187104000 + 17848

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018721aa88 0x1871fb000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001872dd36c 0x1872dc000 + 4972
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001872dcdb4 0x1872dc000 + 3508

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001872dcdb0 0x1872dc000 + 3504
```

Comment: You need to provide a symbolicated crash report with the code that this report references. Otherwise nothing can be said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, was missing assemblyinfo declarations